# How to make the background image of the pseudo element stretch to fit the width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay some text on an image, and also make the background image 0.2 transparent. now my question is: How to make the background image of the pseudo element stretch to fit the width or crop the image to fit the screen（without distort the image）?  Edit the code on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvEdL).

**css:**

```
#main:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg/944px-Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="main">
  Text on top, no big deal, no big deal. Just a little text and stuff. That's all.
</div>
```

Comment: use pixel height for your pseudo element instead percentage

Comment: Use `background-size:cover`?

Comment: See http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ for several methods of background image sizing and text positioning.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are tying to do but you could try adding `background-size:cover` as follows:

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3bvy33a/1/)

**CSS**

```
#main:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg/944px-Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#main:after {
content : "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg/944px-Selwyn_College_Old_Court%2C_Cambridge%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg); 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity : 0.2;
z-index: -1;

background-size: 100% 100%;    /* added*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* optinal*/
```

}

Or in one line syntax like this:

```
background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;
```

For more detail [click.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)